# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have sql query below but i face a problem when execute it.

```
SELECT * from (Select row_number() OVER(Order By FloorUserId) as 'row_number', FloorUserId,
max(CASE WHEN AreaId='[G]' or AreaId=N'L01'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L01',
max(CASE WHEN AreaId='[G]' or AreaId=N'L02'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L02'
from floor, tbuser where FloorUserId= tbuser.userID  
    )  as derivedTable where row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Column 'FloorId' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you displaying the whole query?

Answer (score 3):

- You have MAX which is for aggregates so you'd need GROUP BY Id
- ...this won't then work because you have ROW_NUMBER
- Do you really want a Cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) between floor and user?
- what column belongs to what table?

Perhaps this may help you to get where you want:

```
Select
     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY userid Order By user.Id) as 'row_number', user.Id,
     max(CASE WHEN  floor.AreaId='[G]' or  floor.AreaId=N'L01'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L01',
     max(CASE WHEN floor. AreaId='[G]' or  floor.AreaId=N'L02'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L02'
from
    floor
    JOIN
    user ON floor. = user.    --what?
where
    user.Id = userID 
group by
    user.Id
```

Comment: I figured `WHERE id = userid` is the JOIN criteria.

Comment: The Id is the floor user id.  I miss type it, it should be 'floorusrId'

Comment: SELECT * from (Select row_number() OVER(Order By FloorUserId) as 'row_number', FloorUserId,
max(CASE WHEN AreaId='[G]' or AreaId=N'L01'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L01',
max(CASE WHEN AreaId='[G]' or AreaId=N'L02'  THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) as 'L02'
from floor, tbuser where Floor.FloorUserId= tbuser.userID  
    )  as derivedTable where row_number BETWEEN 1 AND 20

Answer (score 0):

You can only use fields that are part of a group by clause when you use aggregrates (like max).

So get rid of the '*' if you want other fields add them into a group by clause.