# How to use Max method for 2 Column

Tags: sql

i have a problem with using max method in sql
when i want run this query it give me this error

```
select max(id),oid,ofactid,obtype,obcount,
       ofi,osaved,osum,ototalsum,oworkdate,max(lastdate) 
from [blokDB].[dbo].[tblOrdersBuy] 
where oid=1
```

return this error

Column 'blokDB.dbo.tblOrdersBuy.ofactid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114112/column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-ag)

Comment: edit for format.   When you are doing a max, you are doing an 'aggregate', and all aggregates need to have a group by so the database knows what you want to find the max for.  Do you want the max ID for each unique combination of oid,ofactid,obtype,obcount,
       ofi,osaved,osum,ototalsum,oworkdate?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want the row with the most recent row for a given id.  Instead of using `max()`, use `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 ob.*
from [blokDB].[dbo].[tblOrdersBuy] ob
where oid = 1
order by lastdate desc;
```